# Coinbase api returning mostly empty arrey

Tags: php, arrays, coinbase-api

I am trying to test coinbase api. Api authorized fine but most functions are returning empty arrey, bellow is my code sample

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;

$apiKey='********';
$apiSecret='********;';

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();
$auth = $client->getCurrentAuthorization();
$user = $client->getCurrentUser();
$paymentMethods = $client->getPaymentMethods();

echo "accounts arrey". json_encode($accounts)."<hr/>";//empty arrey
echo "primary account arrey".json_encode($account)." <hr/>";//empty arrey
echo "current auth arrey".json_encode($auth)."<hr/>";//printing data perfectly
echo "current user arrey".json_encode($user)."<hr/>";//empty array 
echo "payment methods arrey".json_encode($paymentMethods)."<hr/>";//empty array 


?>
```

All of echo printing empty array except `$auth`bellow is output screenshot

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: If some function of the library not working you should maybe ask the creator of this library. I think you use the official [PHP wrapper for coinbase API](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) or? I just had a short look on it and the function which returns an empty array use API endpoints which are not described in the official API documentation.

Comment: Yes I used official api, ok tnx for your suggestion. Let me  open issue on github.actually they reply after 2/3 days thats why I posted here if someone can help me to solve quickly. And tnx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by using $response=$client->decodeLastResponse(); and echo $response